# ROS command not working when called from Dockerfile and script

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, ros

I'm creating a docker container to execute a ROS package.

```
FROM ros:melodic
COPY . /rosdata
WORKDIR /rosdata
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh && chmod +x setupROS.sh && bash -c "./setupROS.sh"
```

This setup script is probably a bit more bloated than it needs to be from debugging attempts and currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y wget apt-utils
sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | apt-key add -
apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y ros-melodic-pcl-conversions ros-melodic-pcl-ros
apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive rosdep install --as-root apt:false --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic -y
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive catkin_make
```

Everything seems fine, until the last command fails with

> ./setupROS.sh: line 10: catkin_make: command not found

If I comment out this last command in the shellscript, only run the previous instructions automatically and then open an interactive session (docker run -it) and run this catkin_make by hand, it works as expected.
Whether or not I include the DEBIAN_FRONTEND variable in this line makes no difference.

What could be the reason catkin_make fails when run in a script called from a Dockerfile, but not when run by hand?

Comment: Other [tag:docker] [tag:ros] questions seem to depend heavily on modifying shell dotfiles.  This isn't something you usually do in Docker (many common paths _ignore_ shell dotfiles altogether); do you need some form of `. ~/.bashrc` or some such?

Comment: @DavidMaze Not that I'm aware of. I've tried opening a session with "bash --noprofile --norc" in the docker exit -it session and catkin_make still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, `catkin_make` is added to path when we run the line source `/opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`. Typically this line is added to `.bashrc` at the end of installation.  Maybe the environment you are running your script in doesn't inherit the same `PATH` (similar to when you run things as sudo).  I'd suggest just adding the `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` line to your script and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition To @Vik Answer:

Beside Sourcing `/opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` in either `.bashrc` or inside your `sh` file ,

you need to be inside your catkin workspace in order for `catkin_make` work. I suggest you use `catkin build` (different workspace)instead of `catkin_make`(Old version Workspace) which you can specify workspace Folder.